# Drift of values read by Arduino MPU6050 sensor

Tags: arduino, gyro

We are using a GY-521 Arduino MPU6050 breakout board, using [Jeff Rowberg's DMP6 libaries](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/tree/master/Arduino/MPU6050/Examples/MPU6050_DMP6).

However, when we read values from the sensor while it is held stationary, the values drift considerably, until they stabilize at a value after around 1 minute.

Is this expected behavior from these chips with these libraries?  We've tried with more than 4 chips, and all drift.

Notably, the chip does not drift when we use the code at the Arduino playground (http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MPU-6050).

Rowberg's code has additional functions that we need, however.  How can we fix this?

Comment: Same problem here. I've also tried to decrease sensitivity but it seems DMP6 is already set to least sensitive settings. This page here http://www.inventige.com/decrease-gyroscope-drift-errors-via-runge-kutta-4th-order/ suggests RK4 filtering for decreasing drift errors.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.instructables.com/id/Guide-to-gyro-and-accelerometer-with-Arduino-inclu/) which explains compensating MPU6050 drifts with Kalman or Complimentary filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to compensate for temperature? It is not coïncidence that the device has an integratged temperature sensor.

> **7.19 Digital Output Temperature Sensor**
>
> An on chip temperature sensor and ADC are used to measure the MPU-60X0
>   die temperature. The readings from the ADC can be read from the FIFO
>   or the Sensor Data registers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the compensation should be done?

Comment: Sorry, never did that myself.